# Eclipse can't include opencv2 header files

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've created an Android Application Project in Eclipse Juno, and after I've added native support to this project (Android Tools -> Add Native Support). So Eclipse has added in the project automatically a jni directory, within which a .cpp file and the file Android.mk.

Then I've build the project, without errors.

In order to use opencv for android libraries (2.4.5), I've added the path to the 'include' directory of these libraries in the project (Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path And Symbols -> Include Diretories). I've also set in the Eclipse Preferences -> NDK the correct path to the ndk directory in my pc, to make possible to execute ndk-build when I build the projects.

But, if i try to include in the .cpp file:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

The console show me this result:

```
12:24:25 **** Build of configuration Default for project ProvaVideoCapture ****
"C:\\Users\\Micaela\\Desktop\\Android\\android-ndk-r8e\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
"Compile++ thumb : jniVideoCapture <= jniVideoCapture.cpp
jni/jniVideoCapture.cpp:4:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/jniVideoCapture/jniVideoCapture.o] Error 1

12:24:26 Build Finished (took 282ms)
```

My Android.mk file is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := jniVideoCapture
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jniVideoCapture.cpp


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The Application.mk file that I've added manually (it has not been automatically added by Eclipse) is:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, or what I've done wrong.

Could you help me?

Comment: I've modified the question.

Comment: you miss LOCAL_C_INCLUDES. Mine is LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../OpenCV/includ

Answer (score 0):

Add path like below to your `Android.mk` file and check

`include E:/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk`

Sample Android.mk for reference

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on


include E:/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk
include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := firstcv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```